# How to create generic route handler in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to create a route handler that will redirect to action/controller depends on the url. For example in ASP.NET MVC 4,5 we could create custom route class and override GetRouteData method  and set own route values, e.g.

```
 public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext){

  RouteData data = base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
  data.Values["controller"] = "SomeController";
  data.Values["action"] = "SomeAction";

  return data;
}
```

I tried to do the same in ASP.NET Core, but there is no posibility to override 
GetRouteData method.
Are there any other tricks?

Comment: Could you use route constraints, that is, the IRouteConstraint interface? found blog post here: https://tommyb.com/customizing-asp-net-cores-route-constraints-and-model-binding/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1 by using Action filters**

[Action filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters)

```
public class SampleActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var myController = ((MyController)context.Controller);
        context.Result = myController.RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController");
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {            
    }
}
```

Just note that method **RedirectToAction()** is part of **MyController** class. (Controller class already has this method, but it's protected)

Do not forget to register it **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(typeof(SampleActionFilter));
    });
}
```

**Solution 2 by using IRouter**

```
class MyRouter : IRouter
{
    private readonly IRouter _defaulRouter;

    public MyRouter(IRouter defaulRouter)
    {
        _defaulRouter = defaulRouter;
    }

    public async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        // Set controller and action based on context.HttpContext.Request url
        context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "Home";
        context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "About";
        await _defaulRouter.RouteAsync(context);
    }

    public VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(VirtualPathContext context)
    {
        return _defaulRouter.GetVirtualPath(context);
    }
}
```

**Startup.Configure**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.Routes.Add(new MyRouter(routes.DefaultHandler));
});
```

Comment: Note that `RedirectToAction` actually sends a redirect HTTP response to the client, requesting them to make another request at the redirected location. OP on the other hand appears to want to retarget a request on the fly to a different action without the user noticing.